# To prove: $n!=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \binom{n}{r} (n-r)^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

How to algebraically prove that $$n!=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \binom{n}{r} (n-r)^n$$

I was trying to find number of onto functions from $A$ to $A$ containing $n$ elements.

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle I am getting 
$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \binom{n}{r} (n-r)^n.$$

We can also do it by simple combinatorics, as every element has to have a pre-image and number of elements in the domain equal to the number of elements in the codomain, the number of functions is $n!.$

Is there an algebraic way to prove these two are equal?

Comment: How about mathematical induction?

Comment: Using the Binomial Theorem, you have: $$\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\dbinom{n}{r}(n-r)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\dbinom{n}{r}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\dbinom{n}{k}n^k(-r)^{n-k}\right)$$ This might help. I haven't checked, though.

Comment: If you don't like to use MI, you may try to expand the RHS:
$n!=n(n-1)(n-2)....(2)(1)$

Comment: @Jerry how to use mathematical induction here? I tried but couldn't get it.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe how to get that result you have mentioned?

Comment: @ATHARVA I used the Binomial Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: @InterstellarProbe  I know binomial theorem. I didn't saw your expression properly ,got it now. But how to take it forward from there.

Answer (score 10):

It  is convenient to use the  *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write for instance

$$n![z^n]e^{rz}=r^n$$

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^n}&\color{blue}{(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}(n-r)^n}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^{n-r}\binom{n}{r}r^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^{n-r}\binom{n}{r}n![z^n]e^{rz}\tag{2}\\
> &=n![z^n]\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\left(e^{z}\right)^r(-1)^{n-r}\tag{3}\\
> &=n![z^n](e^{z}-1)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=n![z^n](z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots)^n\tag{5}\\
> &\color{blue}{=n!}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we change the order of summation by setting $r \rightarrow n-r$ and use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and do a little rearrangement as preparation for the next step.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (5) we do the series expansion of $e^{z}$ and see the smallest exponent of $z$ in $(e^{z}-1)^n$ is $\color{blue}{n}$. So, we will only use the constant $\color{blue}{1}$ in the series expansion.

Comment: Cool solution, but I think you should flesh out the passage from (2) to(3) a bit more.

Comment: @goblin:  Thanks.  :-) I've added some information which might be helpful.

Comment: @FelixMarin: Many thanks. Typo corrected.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, we have that
$$
n! = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  n \hfill \cr 
  k \hfill \cr}  \right)\left( {n - k} \right)^{\,n} }  = \left. {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  n \hfill \cr 
  k \hfill \cr}  \right)\left( {x - k} \right)^{\,n} \;} } \right|_{\,x\, = \,n}  = \left. {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  n \hfill \cr 
  k \hfill \cr}  \right)p_{\,n} (x - k)\;} } \right|_{\,x\, = \,n} 
$$
for any $x \in \mathbb R$ or even $x \in \mathbb C$, and for any polynomial in $x$ of degree $n$, with leading coefficient $1$.

That's because the [*Backward Difference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference), defined as
$$
\nabla _x f(x) = f(x) - f(x - 1)
$$
and which reiterates as
$$
\nabla _x ^{\,n} f(x) = \nabla _x ^{\,n - 1} f(x) - \nabla _x ^{\,n - 1} f(x - 1) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  n \hfill \cr 
  k \hfill \cr}  \right)f\left( {x - k} \right)} 
$$
when applied to a polynomial of degree $n$
$$
p_{\,n} (x) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m\, \le \,n} {a_{\,n} x^{\,n} } 
$$
gives
$$
\nabla _n ^{\,n} p_{\,n} (n) = \left. {\nabla _x ^{\,n} p_{\,n} (x)\,} \right|_{\,x\, = \,n}  = a_{\,n} \,n!
$$
as it is easy to verify, if you know Stirling Numbers and Falling factorials.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x),$$ $$Df(x)=f'(x).$$ Since
$$f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(x)+\frac{f''(x)}{2!}+\frac{f'''(x)}{3!}+\cdots,$$
we have
$$\Delta=D+\frac{D^2}{2!}+\frac{D^3}{3!}+\cdots.$$

Hence $$\Delta^nf(x)=\left(D+\frac{D^2}{2!}+\frac{D^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)^nf(x).\label{1}\tag{1}$$

Applying successively the finite difference operator, we obtain
$$\Delta^nf(x)=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r {n\choose r}f(x+n-r)\label{2}\tag{2}.$$

If $f(x)=x^n$ then $D^nf(x)=n!$, and $D^mf(x)=0$ if $m>n$. Thus combining \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} we get
$$n!=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r {n\choose r}(x+n-r)^n.$$
The desired result follows by setting $x=0$. Note that this works in greater generality.

Comment: yes, this is an interesting recasting of the answer I gave in terms of "backward" instead of "forward" difference .