# simplifying triple summations from series expansion

Tags: summation, gamma-function, binomial-theorem

I have the following equation I would like to extract $x^k$ out of
$$
\sum^\infty_{k=0}x^k \Gamma \bigg(l,\frac{ax-1}{a^2}\bigg)
$$
I start by expanding the incomplete gamma function, and then the ensuing exponential
$$
\begin{align}
&= \sum^\infty_{k=0}x^k\Gamma(l)e^{-\frac{ax-1}{a^2}}\sum^{l-1}_{m=0}\bigg(\frac{ax-1}{a^2}\bigg)^m\frac{1}{m!}\\
&=\Gamma(l)\sum^\infty_{k=0}x^k\sum^\infty_{n=0}\bigg(\frac{1-ax}{a^2}\bigg)^n\frac{1}{n!}\sum^{l-1}_{m=0}\bigg(-\frac{1-ax}{a^2}\bigg)^m\frac 1{m!}
\end{align}
$$
I'm then not sure how to proceed.

My attempt is to pull the terminal sum out front and change the starting index of $k$
$$
=\Gamma(l)\sum^{l-1}_{m=0}\sum^\infty_{k=m}x^k\bigg(-\frac{1-ax}{a^2}\bigg)^m\frac 1{m!}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\bigg(\frac{1-ax}{a^2}\bigg)^n\frac{1}{n!}
$$
I think then perhaps a binomial expansion of $1-ax$ to isolate $x$ and recombine as 
$$
=\Gamma(l)\sum^{l-1}_{m=0}\sum^\infty_{k=m}\sum^m_{j=0}\begin{pmatrix} m \\ j
\end{pmatrix} (a^{-2})^j(a^{-1})^{m-j}\frac 1{m!}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^n_{q=0}\begin{pmatrix} n \\ q
\end{pmatrix} \left(a^{-2}\right)^{q}\left(-a^{-1}\right)^{n-q}(x)^{m-j+k+n-q}\frac{1}{n!}
$$
I now have $x$ on its own, but have no idea how to pull it out front. I then want to reuse the exponential and incomplete gamma functions to tidy the resulting formula up. I'd imagine a quotient containing the incomplete gamma function as a final result.

** Edit **

In a similar (and simpler) example we would have 
$$
\sum^\infty_{k=0} x^k \sum^n_{m=0}\frac{(nx)^m}{m!} = \sum^n_{m=0}\sum^\infty_{k=m}x^k\frac{n^m}{m!} = \sum^\infty_{k=0}x^k\sum^{(k,n)}_{m=0}\frac{n^m}{m!} = e^n\sum^\infty_{k=0}x^k\frac{\Gamma((k,n)+1,n)}{\Gamma((k,n)+1)}
$$
where $(k,n)$ denotes the lesser of $k$ or $n$. I wish to retain the sum over k and pull $x^k$ outside (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$.

> We obtain for $j\geq 0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^j]\sum^\infty_{k=0}&x^k\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{1-ax}{a^2}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}\sum^{l-1}_{m=0}\left(-\frac{1-ax}{a^2}\right)^m\frac 1{m!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^j[x^{j-k}]\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{1-ax}{a^2}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}\sum^{l-1}_{m=0}\left(-\frac{1-ax}{a^2}\right)^m\frac 1{m!}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^j\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^{l-1}\frac{(-1)^m}{n!m!a^{2(n+m)}}[x^k](1-ax)^{n+m}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^j\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{l-1}\frac{(-1)^m}{n!m!a^{2^{(n+m)}}}[x^k]\sum_{r=0}^{n+m}\binom{n+m}{r}(-ax)^r\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^j\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^{l-1}\binom{n+m}{k}\frac{(-1)^{m+j}}{n!m!a^{2(n+m)-k}}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we select the coefficient of $x^j$ and apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$. We set the upper limit of the outer sum to $j$ since higher indices do not contribute to $[x^j]$.
- In (2) we change the order of summation of the outer sum by letting $k\to j-k$ and do some rearrangements.
- In (3) we expand the binomial as preparation for the next step.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^k$. Note that the double sum is zero as long as $n+m<k$.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I have never heard of this operator before! I'm not sure I understand (2) --> (3)? Could I still pull $\sum_k x^k$ out of this expression? (I will edit the question to show what I mean in more detail.) Once again, thank you for your time!

Comment: @RedPen: You're welcome. I've added a step which might be helpful.

Comment: thank you once again for your helpful edit. Would I be correct in thinking that this gives me the coefficient of the $j$th term? I could then write $\sum_{j=0}^\infty f_jx^j$ (where $f_j$ is your highlighted formula)? This would then be my closed form series?

Comment: @RedPen: Yes, it's exactly as you indicate.

Comment: In going from (1) to (2), when we change the index and the order of summation. How do we get $j$ from setting $k\rightarrow j-k$?  If there were terms present in $k$ in the equation, would they also convert to  $k\rightarrow j-k$ too?

Comment: @RedPen: There was a mistake when applying the *coefficient of* operator the first time. I've mixed up $k$ and $j$. This implies that we also cannot get rid of the outer sum. It's now corrected. Thanks. ... And yes, setting $k\to j-k$ applies then to each occurrence of $k$.

Comment: Sorry to keep pestering you (I hope you don't mind me asking one more question). In a very similar problem, on step (2), I have $$\sum^j_{k=0}P(k)[z^{j-2k}]A(z)$$ If I choose $2k\rightarrow  j-k$ then $k\rightarrow (j-k)/2$, which doesn't seem good to have non-integer index. In this case, how can I proceed to re-order the summations?

Comment: (I would like to give you a bounty to say thank you for your help too!)

Comment: @RedPen: No worries. :-) In this case it might be more convenient to keep the exponent $j-2k$ without changing the order of the sum. In fact it depends on the structure of $A(z)$. If $A(z)$ is a power series, the upper limit of the sum is $\lfloor{j/2}\rfloor$ instead of $j$ to respect that $j-2k\geq 0$. Many thanks for your nice bounty offer, I do appreciate it. But, if you want to keep your rep, this would be also fine to me. (It's the idea which counts. :-))

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Ah, yes, that makes sense. I have $$[z^j] \sum^\infty_{k=0}P(k)z^{2k}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{1-ax}{a^2}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}\sum^{l-1}_{m=0}\left(-\frac{1-ax}{a^2}\right)^m\frac 1{m!}$$ So, the process is identical apart from the sum over $k$ ends at $j/2$ and that $2k\rightarrow j-k$? (The bounty is yours, I really appreciate your help and for introducing this operator to me, but I can only award it in 24 hours). :)

Comment: @RedPen: Many thanks for the bounty, this is very kind of you. Yes, the process is identical. You might find *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827331/to-prove-n-sum-limits-r-0n-1r-binomnr-n-rn/2827397#2827397)* and *[this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830860/binomial-sums-from-bieberbach-conjecture/2837554#2837554)* helpful, which show the *coeffcient of* operator in action in slightly more complex applications.

Comment: @RedPen: Many thanks for granting the bounty! :-)